# C++ Euler-Problem 14 Program Freezing

Tags: c++

I'm working on Euler Problem 14:
http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=14

I figured the best way would be to create a vector of numbers that kept track of how big the series was for that number... for example from 5 there are 6 steps to 1, so if ever reach the number 5 in a series, I know I have 6 steps to go and I have no need to calculate those steps. With this idea I coded up the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> sizes(1);
    sizes.push_back(1);
    sizes.push_back(2);
    int series, largest = 0, j;
    for (int i = 3; i <= 1000000; i++)
    {
        series = 0;
        j = i;
        while (j > (sizes.size()-1))
        {
            if (j%2)
            {
                j=(3*j+1)/2;
                series+=2;
            }
            else
            {
                j=j/2;
                series++;
            }
        }
        series+=sizes[j];
        sizes.push_back(series);
        if (series>largest)
            largest=series;
        cout << setw(7) << right << i << "::" << setw(5) << right << series << endl;
    }
        cout << largest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to work relatively well for smaller numbers but this specific program stalls at the number 113382. Can anyone explain to me how I would go about figuring out why it freezes at this number?

Is there some way I could modify my algorithim to be better? I realize that I am creating duplicates with the current way I'm doing it:
for example, the series of 3 is 3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1.  So I already figured out the sizes for 10,5,16,8,4,2,1 but I will duplicate those solutions later.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Word to the wise: just go with `long` for most Project Euler stuff; you're hardly ever pressed for space if you're doing it correctly and you will avoid a lot of problems with running over int boundaries.

Comment: @Amber: long=int on most 32 bit systems. One should use "long long", which works on VC++ exactly as with GNU C++. Or, if that's not enough, use a library for arbitrary huge integers.

Comment: @Doc - ugh, latenight typo. I had actually been meaning to say `long long`. ><

Answer (score 3):

Have you ruled out integer overflow? Can you guarantee that the result of `(3*j+1)/2` will always fit into an `int`?

Does the result change if you switch to a larger data type?

EDIT: The last forum post at http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5427293 seems to confirm this. I found this by googling for `113382 3n+1`.

Comment: I changed everything to long including the vector and I still freeze at 113382. If it were using too much memory would it still freeze at the same number?

EDIT::** After reading your edit I'm wondering if somehow my useage of longs is incorrect or maybe somehow my default is 32-bit like an integer. Any way to double check?

Comment: Yep, `j` is increasing beyond max int (bad luck of a string of even numbers after the `j=(3j+1)`).  `long long` keeps going. (1million yields 153)

Comment: `long` is 32bit, just like `int`.  Use `long long`.

Comment: @Tim,@Stephen: I was thinking of Java, where `long` is always 64 bit. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are severely overcomplicating things. Why are you even using vectors for this?

Your problem, I think, is overflow. Use unsigned ints everywhere.

Here's a working code that's much simpler and that works (it doesn't work with signed ints however).

```
int main()
{

    unsigned int maxTerms = 0;
    unsigned int longest = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 3; i <= 1000000; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int tempTerms = 1;
        unsigned int j = i;
        while (j != 1)
        {
             ++tempTerms;

             if (tempTerms > maxTerms)
             {
                 maxTerms = tempTerms;
                 longest = i;
             }

             if (j % 2 == 0)
             {
                 j /= 2;
             }
             else
             {
                 j = 3*j + 1;
             }
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", maxTerms, longest);

    return 0;
}
```

Optimize from there if you really want to.

Comment: I tried brute force and it would've taken hours to reach the end

Comment: @Tim - the code I posted takes less than a second to provide the correct answer on my machine. There is no way it takes hours, unless your CPU is 20 years old.

Answer (score 1):

When i = 113383, your j overflows and becomes negative (thus never exiting the "while" loop).

I had to use "unsigned long int" for this problem.

Comment: Yea, stephen found that out too, thanks!
How exactly does an unsigned long int work? Can it scale as large as you need it to?

Comment: No, it's just 0 to 2*MAX_LONG. It happens that "unsigned long int" just fits the numbers for Euler-14, or you would have to use long long int or some "BigInt" library.

Comment: @Tim: An `int` reserves one bit for sign.  `unsigned int` assumes positive integers, so it doesn't use that bit.  That means `unsigned int` can hold twice as many values as `int`.  Apparently, luckily, this problem fits in `unsigned int` range as well.  As we discussed, `long` == `int` (which can represent 2^32 numbers), but `long long` has 64 bits - so it can represent 2^64 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is overflow. Just because the sequence starts below 1 million does not mean that it cannot go above 1 million later. In this particular case, it overflows and goes negative resulting in your code going into an infinite loop. I changed your code to use "long long" and this makes it work.

But how did I find this out? I compiled your code and then ran it in a debugger. I paused the program execution while it was in the loop and inspected the variables. There I found that j was negative. That pretty much told me all I needed to know. To be sure, I added a `cout << j;` as well as an `assert(j > 0)` and confirmed that j was overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a large array rather than a vector, then you will be able to avoid those duplicates you mention as for every number you calculate you can check if it's in the array, and if not, add it. It's probably actually more memory efficient that way too. Also, you might want to try using unsigned long as it's not clear at first glance how large these numbers will get.

Comment: More ideal for "check if it's there, if not, add it" would be a `map`.

Comment: What would be the best way to determine if an element is in an array without searching through it? That seems to be pretty ineffecient EVERY time I make any change to the number

Comment: Use each array index as a spot to store the length of the series starting at that number. initialize each to -1 or something so you know if it's been already calculated.

Answer (score 0):

i stored the length of the chain for every number in an array.. and during brute force whenever i got a number less than that being evaluated for, i just added the chain length for that lower number and broke out of the loop.
For example, i already know the Collatz sequence for 10 is 7 lengths long.
now when i'm evaluating for 13, i get 40, then 20, then 10.. which i have already evaluated. so the total count is 3 + 7.
the result on my machine (for upto 1 million) was 0.2 secs. with pure brute force that was 5 seconds.